# material Ui with tailwind in next js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui, tailwind-css, server-side-rendering

for my next js project tailwind is the main styling library, I used materal UI for javascript snippets, mui pagination and radio group are working fine in my local machine but in server mui classes are being renamed, I came to know from stackoverflow that mui needs to configure for next js, I searched about this in chat GPT and I got the following code.

```
import { CacheProvider, EmotionCache } from "@emotion/react";
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";
import { ServerStyleSheets } from "@mui/styles";
import createCache from "@emotion/cache";
import { styled } from "@mui/system";
import { AppContext, AppInitialProps, AppPropsType } from "next/app";
import { ReactElement } from "react";
import { NextPageContext } from "next";

interface MyAppProps extends AppPropsType {
  emotionCache?: EmotionCache;
}

const cache = createCache({ key: "css", prepend: true });
const theme = createTheme();

const StyledComponent = styled("div")({});

interface NextPageContextWithRenderPage extends NextPageContext {
  renderPage: () => Promise<{
    html: string;
    head?: JSX.Element[];
  }>;
}

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps, emotionCache }: MyAppProps): ReactElement {
  return (
    <CacheProvider value={emotionCache || cache}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <StyledComponent>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </StyledComponent>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </CacheProvider>
  );
}

MyApp.getInitialProps = async ({
  Component,
  ctx,
}: AppContext): Promise<AppInitialProps & { emotionCache: EmotionCache }> => {
  // Generate server-side styles
  const sheets = new ServerStyleSheets();
  const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage;

  try {
    ctx.renderPage = () =>
      originalRenderPage({
        enhanceApp: (App: ReactElement) => (props) =>
          sheets.collect(<App {...props} />),
      });

    const initialProps = await App.getInitialProps({ Component, ctx });
    return {
      ...initialProps,
      // Styles fragment is rendered after the app and page rendering finish.
      emotionCache: sheets.getStyleElement(),
    };
  } finally {
    ctx.renderPage = originalRenderPage;
  }
};

interface MyAppInitialProps extends AppInitialProps {
  styles: JSX.Element[];
}

export type { MyAppInitialProps };

export default MyApp;
```

But adding this in my _app.js component tailwind classes are not working at all.How to solve this? please help me

I tried all the ways available in stackoverflow, but I got no solution related to solve the tailwind issue, I am overwriting mui classes for fonts and color changing in my project, I want those classes to be consistent in server as they are in my local

Comment: Try adding prefix to tailwind classes https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#prefix - should help in case classes are overwritten